# get Spanish characters using request.getparameter() not working

Tags: java, jsp, request

I'm trying to get a Spanish characters in Java using request.getParameter() method. But it is returning junk characters.

**URL:** [http://localhost:8080/myweb/encode.jsp?first_name=Ramón](http://localhost:8080/myweb/encode.jsp?first_name=Ram%C3%B3n) Martínez

**Encoded URL:** http://localhost:8080/myweb/encode.jsp?first_name=Ram%C3%B3n%20Mart%C3%ADnez%20

**Example 1:**

**JSP CODE:**

```
   <%  request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
  String firstname= request.getParameter("first_name");
    %>
    <%=firstname %>
```

**Example 2:**

**JSP CODE:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils,java.net.URLDecoder,java.net.URLEncoder"   %>

      <%  request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
String firstname = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(((String[])request.getParameterMap().get("first_name"))[0], "UTF-8");
%>


<%=firstname %>
```

**Output:**

```
RamÃ³n MartÃ­nez
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Ramón Martínez
```

We tried by editing server.xml using the following suggestion ([How to get UTF-8 working in Java webapps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138948/how-to-get-utf-8-working-in-java-webapps)) . It's working but we don't want to use this solution by editing server.xml.

We tried by adding following code,  but this is not working.

```
CODE : request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086190/request-getparameter-does-not-display-properly-character-encoding-in-java-serv and also refer http://balusc.blogspot.in/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html for further reading

Comment: Don't just append raw values in the query part of your url, you need to encode them properly using a helper like `java.net.URLEncoder`

Comment: @MayankPandya , Thanks for your reply i have tried your suggestion, but still it reproducing junk characters. I have updated my question.

Comment: @morgano , Thanks for your reply, i have tried your code also, but its not working.  I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>` at the very beginning of your main jsp file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already added this code, still its not working